# Rotating a Cocos2d sprite to match a joystick

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, rotation, joystick

I'm using a SneakyJoystick in Cocos2d, and I'm trying to get a sprite to rotate to face the same direction as the joystick is pointed (this is top down).

I can get it to rotate to face it, but it snaps into position as the rotation is updated every frame or so.

How can I make the sprite rotate smoothly towards the target angle, without jumping to it? I wasn't able to figure out how to do this with a CCRotateTo because the angle to rotate towards could change at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this simply by using a rotation method that I made, which rotates the node/sprite in the correct direction at the correct amount each update.

```
- (void)rotateNode:(CCNode*)aNode degrees:(float)targetRotation withSpeed:(float)rotationSpeed withTimeDelta:(ccTime)dt
{
    rotationSpeed = rotationSpeed * dt;

    // Convert the difference between the two angles to radians
    float diff = (targetRotation - aNode.rotation) * (M_PI / 180);
    // Find the rotation of the vector created by the sin and cos of the difference
    float rotationDifference = atan2f(sinf(diff),cosf(diff));
    // Rotate the clip accordingly
    aNode.rotation += MAX(
                         MIN(
                             (180/M_PI) * rotationDifference,rotationSpeed), -rotationSpeed
                         );
}
```

Comment: Say  from where did you get this formula ? its working at my code using cocos , but it is upside down

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.5f angle:CC_DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(90.0f)];
```

Obtain the Angle between the last Update the current Update, also if you wanted it so the character had a set time to turn around, you can scale your duration by the amount of the angle.

Comment: I'll give it a go, but what stops the CCRotates from conflicting with each other when, say, a CCRotate hasn't finished by the time another is added?